# Multiple look-arounds and ignore inside tags

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to find text that is not part of another word (have this working) but I also want to **not** find text if it is inside an `<a>` tag

```
"Java <li>Javascript</li> <a href="">Some Java here</a> more java"

var regex2 = new RegExp(`(?<![a-z])Java(?![a-z])`, "gi");

text = text.replace(regex2, '++JavaUpdated++');
```

Above works but below with additional lookarounds doesn't

```
var regex2 = new RegExp(`(?<![a-z])(?<!<a.*)Java(?!.*<\/a>)(?![a-z])`, "gi");
```

Comment: Careful using Regex alone for parsing HTML. I've been there - it's not enough on its own when you have nested elements.

Comment: yes unfortunately I cant avoid it, I have one regex that adds links but if it finds the word again inside the <a> tag it doubles up

Comment: Gotcha. I might have a way around that...but I'm not sure what your HTML actually looks like. I see an out-of-place `<li>` tag here, for example. That could change what the DOM actually becomes.

Comment: sorry ignore <li> was just testing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to split the string on `<a>` tags, then process each part of the string independently, replacing `Java` with `++JavaUpdated++` only when the part doesn't begin with `<a`:

```js
const str = 'Java <li>Javascript</li> <a href="">Some Java here</a> more java';

let newstr = str.split(/(<a.*?<\/a>)/)
                .map(v => (v.slice(0, 2) == '<a') ? v : v.replace(/\bJava\b/i, '++JavaUpdated++'))
                .join();

console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but if you insist...

You can use the following regex expression if you're using a browser that allows lookbehinds (see below):

```
(?<![^\s])Java(?![^\s])(?!(.(?!<a))*<\/a>)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0cPbOY/3)

Essentially, we are checking that there is nothing in front or after `Java` except for whitespace, and then use negative lookahead to check for text in tags.

I've noticed you are using a **negative lookbehind** in your original regex - this is actually not supported by JavaScript pre-2018, so you might want to be aware of that. Lookbehinds are only available in [browsers supporting ECMA2018 standard](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind).

If you want to solve this without negative lookbehind, you could try:

```
(?:\s$|^)Java(?![^\s])(?!(.(?!<a))*<\/a>)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0cPbOY/4)

Essentially saying not to match `Java` if preceeded by anything except a whitespace or a start of line (else, would be part of a word).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to handle where text might break into separate Text nodes, the snippet below ought to cover the logic. The idea is to just walk the Text nodes in the DOM and ignore any anchor tags along the way.

```js
// Your RegExp, just as a literal
const re = /(?<![a-z])Java(?![a-z])/gi

const walkTextNodesIgnoringAnchors = (el, fn) =>
  el.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    // Ignore anchors
    if (child.nodeName === 'A') return
    
    // On Text nodes, call fn
    else if (child.nodeName === '#text') fn(child)
    
    // Otherwise, recursively walk further down
    else walkTextNodes(child, fn)
  })

const textEl = document.querySelector('.js-text')

walkTextNodesIgnoringAnchors(textEl, (textNode) => {
  textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(re, '++JavaUpdated++')
})
```

```html
<div class="js-text">Java Javascript <a href="">Some Java here</a> more java</div>
```